# Project fails to build with SDK dependency in Dependent project

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, react-native

I'm building a React Native Module, which relies on an external (3rd party) SDK, for use in my RN project.

The dependent project will build, but the android application will not build.

In the Native Module's build.gradle I have the following:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'src/main/libs'
        }
    }
}
```

In the android app's build.gradle

```
dependencies {
  implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
  implementation project(':react-native-mymodule-sdk')
...
}
```

When building the Android app I get an error:

```
Could not find :third-party-sdk-2.0:.
Searched in the following locations: file:/C:/[path to android project]/app/libs/third-party-sdk-2.0.aar

Required by:
    project :app > project :react-native-mymodule-sdk
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this.

There were a few problems.  First, the Gradle version in the SDK project was severely out-of-date.  After updating to the latest version the Google repository needed to be added.

I also needed to add the allProjects -> dependencies section to the main application build.gradle file as well.